# Detect if a dispatch_async method is still running

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, grand-central-dispatch

I have a **loadImages** method

```
- (void)loadImages {
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
       //this method loads images from a url, processes them
       //and then adds them to a property of its view controller 
       //@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *storedImages;
   });
}
```

When a button is clicked a view enters the screen, and **all the images that currently exist** in _storedImages are displayed

```
- (void)displayImages {
   for (NSString *link in _storedImages) {
      //displayImages
   }
}
```

The problem with this setup is, that **if the user clicks the button before all the images are loaded, not all the images are presented on the screen.**

Hence, I would like to **display an SVProgressHUD if** the button is clicked, and the **loadImages dispatch_async method is still running**.

So, **how do I keep track of when this dispatch_async is completed?** Because if I know this, then I can display an SVProgressHUD until it is completed.

*On a side note, if you know how to load/display the images dynamically that info would be helpful too*, i.e. you click the button and then as you see the current images, more images are downloaded and displayed

Thank you from a first time iOS developer!

---

Ok I *found a solution but it is incredibly inefficient*, I am sure there's a better way to do this

> ```
> 1. Keep a boolean property doneLoadingImages which is set to NO
> 2. After the dispatch method finishes, set it to YES
> 3. In the display images method, have a while (self.doneLoadingImages == NO)
> //display progress HUD until all the images a loaded
> ```

Comment: You can call a function at the end of your method, which is a common way to deal with GCD "delegates". I'm more curious as to why your images stop loading, have you tried finding other people's asynchronous image view implementations? There's a lot on the web, might be helpful

Comment: The images don't stop loading, they just are not displayed. For example, if I leave the image list view to go back to the main view, and I click the button again, all the images are there, it's just that the image list view never updates

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Keep in mind that `NSMutableArray` is not thread-safe.  You must ensure that you don't  try to access it from two threads at once.

Using a boolean to track whether you're still loading images is fine.  Make `loadImages` look like this:

```
- (void)loadImages {
    self.doneLoadingImages = NO;

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{

        while (1) {
            UIImage *image = [self bg_getNextImage];
            if (!image)
                break;
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self addImage:image];
            });
        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self didFinishLoadingImages];
        });

    });
}
```

So we send ourselves `addImage:` on the main queue for each image.  The `addImage:` method will only be called on the main thread, so it can safely access `storedImages`:

```
- (void)addImage:(UIImage *)image {
    [self.storedImages addObject:image];
    if (storedImagesViewIsVisible) {
        [self updateStoredImagesViewWithImage:image];
    }
}
```

We send ourselves `didFinishLoadingImages` when we've loaded all the images.  Here, we can update the `doneLoadingImages` flag, and hide the progress HUD if necessary:

```
- (void)didFinishLoadingImages {
    self.doneLoadingImages = YES;
    if (storedImagesViewIsVisible) {
        [self hideProgressHUD];
    }
}
```

Your button action can then check the `doneLoadingImages` property:

```
- (IBAction)displayImagesButtonWasTapped:(id)sender {
    if (!storedImagesViewIsVisible) {
        [self showStoredImagesView];
        if (!self.doneLoadingImages) {
            [self showProgressHUD];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what does `while (1)` do? @rob-mayoff

Comment: This seems like a solid idea. I am stilly trying to get it to work with my code though, once I get it to work, I'll upvote and checkmark,  till then, I'll let anyone have a go at the question in case they have any other ideas.

Comment: This works, and it's actually faster than my method of sending arrays to different methods. In future, I will try not to use an array. :)

Comment: Hi Rob, you did a brilliant job with this, can you help me out on a similar question that relates to AFNetworking, thanks a lot! I greatly appreciate it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15837760/load-images-one-at-a-time  @rob-mayoff

Comment: @user924 There is; check out `NSThread`'s `executing`, `finished`, and `cancelled` properties. But a dispatch queue does not correspond to a single thread, and properties of a thread don't necessarily apply to a queue. Also please note what the `Thread.getState()` documentation says: “This method is designed for use in monitoring of the system state, not for synchronization control.”

Comment: @robmayoff we're not talking about NSThread here. I know about NSThread but it doesn't have `join` method like Java Thread has

Comment: You asked about `Thread.getState`, so I responded. You didn't ask about `Thread.join`. Perhaps you meant your comment about `getState` as a complaint rather then a question, but that's not how I read it. Perhaps you meant “why doesn't GCD provide a method to ask a queue how many jobs it has left to run”, and I can think of a reason, but it's speculative and I don't want to try to explain it in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do with this kind of problem is basically the following (rough sketch):

```
- (void)downloadImages:(NSArray*)arrayOfImages{

  if([arrayOfImages count] != 0)
  {
     NSString *urlForImage = [arrayOfImages objectAtIndex:0];
     // Start downloading the image

     // Image has been downloaded
     arrayOfImages = [arrayOfImages removeObjectAtIndex:0];
     // Ok let's get the next ones...
     [self downloadImages:arrayOfImages];
  }
  else
  {
   // Download is complete, use your images..
  }
}
```

You can pass the number of downloads that failed, or even a delegate that will receive the images after.

Answer (score 0):

You put a "note" and this may help, it allows you to display the images as they come down, I store the URLs in an array (here it is strings but you could do array of NSURL).

```
for(NSString *urlString in imageURLs)
{
    // Add a downloading image to the array of images
    [storedImages addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"downloading.png"]];

    // Make a note of the image location in the array    
    __block int imageLocation = [storedImages count] - 1; 

    // Setup the request    
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setTimeoutInterval: 10.0];
    request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad;

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                  queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue]
                  completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                  // Check the result
                  NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
                  if (data != nil && error == nil && [httpResponse statusCode] == 200)
                  { 
                      storedImages[imageLocation] = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                      [self reloadImages];
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      // There was an error
                      recommendedThumbs[imageLocation] = [UIImageimageNamed:@"noimage.png"];
                      [self reloadImages]
                  }
           }];
}
```

You then need another method which reloads the display.  If the images are in a table then [[tableview] reloaddata];

```
-(void)reloadImages
```