# Load Images One At A Time

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, afnetworking

So this code basically gets data from a server, creates an image, and then adds it to the view.

However, I would like it to update the view one at a time.

Right now, the view is updated with all the images at once after all are loaded.

I would like to update the view, everytime a new image is uploaded - This should happen in the addImage method, but instead, it is just waiting for all the images to load.

I tried using a dispatch_async to solve this problem, but it did not work.

**So how do I load images one at at a time?**

```
    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation =
        [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                                        success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
       //some code not displayed here that parses the JSON
       for (NSDictionary *image in images){
           if ([[image objectForKey:@"ContentType"] isEqualToString:@"image/png"]){
               NSString *imgLink = [[image objectForKey:@"MediaUrl"] JSONStringWithOptions:JKSerializeOptionPretty includeQuotes:NO error:nil];
               NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
               NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
               UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data cache:NO]
               dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                   [self addImage:img];
                   //This method adds the image to the view
                });
           }
       }
   }
```

---

Update: This is not a tableview, images are added as subviews to a UIView

Comment: Try [self setNeedsDisplay];

Comment: Nope, that had no effect, same result. I have a feeling AFNetworking is causing some interference, but as a first time iOS developer I am not too sure what's the problem. Thanks for the try though! :) @Shmidt

Comment: Try to replace dispatch_async with dispatch_sync

Comment: Thanks once again, but I tried it, and that makes it go on an infinite loop

Comment: Is it possible that what's happening here is that your JSON parsing code is taking a long time, and then the images are all loading relatively quickly? Have you done any analysis of what's taking the most time?

Comment: It also occurs to me that it looks like this is all happening on the main thread, and you should probably not be doing that. So wrap the whole thing in a `dispatch_async` (not on the main thread), then when you want to update the image(s), use another `dispatch_async` (this time on the main thread).

Comment: @livingtech I thought, AFJSONRequestOperation success/failure blocks were automatically set to the background, am I wrong in this assumption?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I have no idea. Never used `AFJSONRequestOperation`.

Comment: Looks like the success/failure blocks run on the main thread by default: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/pull/35

Comment: OK, I still haven't found a good solution to this problem, but that was a handy tip for a first timer like me. So thank you. :)

Comment: @livingtech Actually, your suggestion does not work, as no views are added when I call dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{}); on the entire thing and only dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{}); around the addImage method

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for a form of lazy loading. Try this example: [Apple Lazy Loading example](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html)

Comment: Updated the question. This is not a tableview, I'll still check out the code to see if anything applies to this situation

Comment: The concept should still be the same.

Comment: Checked it out. I am actually already doing something similar to what it says, and it's not working for me, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

```
[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

is a synch operation so you have to wait for each image one by one, a proper lazy loading implementation of the picture based on the url is the best solution, in the meantime you can try to do something like this

```
AFJSONRequestOperation *operation =
[AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                                success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
                                                    //some code not displayed here that parses the JSON
                                                    for (NSDictionary *image in images){
                                                        if ([[image objectForKey:@"ContentType"] isEqualToString:@"image/png"]){
                                                            NSString *imgLink = [[image objectForKey:@"MediaUrl"] JSONStringWithOptions:JKSerializeOptionPretty includeQuotes:NO error:nil];
                                                            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];

                                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
                                                                NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
                                                                UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data cache:NO]
                                                                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                                                    [self addImage:img];
                                                                    //This method adds the image to the view
                                                                });
                                                            })

                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
```

if you want to use this solution a recommend you to create your own concurrent queue rather than use the global_queue

Comment: With this method, the first two images load, and then the rest of the images load all at once, so still not one at a time for some reason